# Convert a column of date numbers into abbreviated month

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a workbook with a column that contains date strings - itself being copied from another source as "paste as values". I need to transform that date number into an abbreviated month - say Jan, Feb, etc.

I tried recording it but the macro doesn't understand autofill for formulas, so if the length of the data changes, more or fewer rows, then it doesn't fill out all the spaces or overfills them.
I tried amending the formula to include whole range with End(xlDown) instead of the fixed range it was giving, but then all the rows down to the very bottom are filled.

Here's the code, but I'm open to any other solution.

```vb
Sub ConvertDateStringToMonth()
'
' ConvertDateStringToMonth Macro
'

'
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Range("I2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=TEXT(RC[-1], ""mmm"")"
    Range("I2").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range([I2], [I2].End(xlDown))
    Range([I2], [I2].End(xlDown)).Select
    Range("H1").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("H1:I1"), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Range("H1:I1").Select
    Columns("I:I").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("H:H").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Range("H1").Select
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, with some googling and common sense I used this and it works:

```
Sub ChangeDate()

    Set DateRange = Range([H2], [H2].End(xlDown))
    
    DateRange.NumberFormat = "mmm"

End Sub
```

Posting here in case anyone else has such a simple question.